# using Count/group by in case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to show all the job positions held by the staff member except 'Relief Teacher' - if the staff is holding more than one job positions. And show Relief teacher if the teacher (staff is holding only one job title of Relief Teacher).

I used Case statement and then used Select statement in it which uses group by, in order to count the number of job positions held by the staff member. But i get an error message saying the subquery returned more than 1 value.
Also, I am trying to exclude 'Relief Teacher' from the JobPositions When I am Displaying all the Job Positions when using STUFF() function. But I am not able to get that.
The second When in Case Statement will show all the job positions when using STUFF. It does not exclude Relief Teacher title from there.

```
SELECT jobpositions.staffid, 
               jobpositions.StaffNameExternal,
               (Case when ((select Count(StaffId) from dbo.vStaffJobPositions group by staffid) =1 and (jobpositiondescription like 'Relief Teacher'))
                then 'Relief Teacher'
                when ((select Count(StaffId) from dbo.vStaffJobPositions group by staffid) >1 )
                then (STUFF((SELECT ' / ' + JobPositionDescription
                FROM dbo.vStaffJobPositions
                FOR XML PATH('')),1,3, '')) 
                end) as StaffPosition
    FROM dbo.vStaffJobPositions JobPositions
```

I have 2 problems with the above code-
1. The Count and groupBy are giving error of Subquery returning more than one value.
2. I want to show only the Job positions held by the staff except Relief Teacher using STUFF()- which is stuff different positions held by them. But I cant EXCLUDE 'Relief Teacher' from there (when they hold more than one job title)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group by is giving more than one record for the count, and you are not filtering for the same user row by row,

So please use the below:-
I created a memory table to show some results, you dont need this part

```
Declare @vStaffJobPositions table(
staffid int,
StaffNameExternal varchar(max),
jobpositiondescription varchar(max)
)
```

And here added some test data as you did not provide any

```
insert into @vStaffJobPositions values
(1,'S1','Relief Teacher'),
(1,'S1','somthing else1'),
(1,'S1','somthing else2'),
(1,'S1','somthing else3'),
(1,'S1','Relief Teacher'),
(2,'S2','Relief Teacher'),
(3,'S3','somthing else1')
```

The SQL part that you can use is as below, change only the table name to yours.

```
select distinct 
    staffid
    ,StaffNameExternal 
    ,case when (select COUNT(*) from @vStaffJobPositions c where c.staffid=x.staffid and jobpositiondescription like 'Relief Teacher')=1 
            then 'Relief Teacher'
            else STUFF((SELECT ' / ' + JobPositionDescription FROM @vStaffJobPositions a 
        where x.staffid=a.staffid and a.jobpositiondescription<>'Relief Teacher' FOR XML PATH('')),1,3, '')
        end as StaffPosition
from @vStaffJobPositions x
```

For the above the results were as below:-

```
staffid StaffNameExternal   StaffPosition
1   S1  somthing else1 / somthing else2 / somthing else3
2   S2  Relief Teacher
3   S3  somthing else1
```

- S2 is only a Relief Teacher
- S1 have a group of positions including 'Relief Teacher' that we are excluding
- S3 have one but not a 'Relief
  Teacher'

hope it helps.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for elaborating and explaining with the temp memory table you created. M

Answer (score 1):

You don't correlate your subqueries, i.e. the return the result for all staff not just the current one.

To check if a staff member is only a relief teacher, you can also just check if the minimum and maximum of their roles is equal and a relief teacher. In the subquery that gets the list of positions just filter relief teachers out in the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT jp1.staffid, 
       jp1.staffnameexternal,
       CASE
         WHEN min(jp1.jobpositiondescription) = max(jp1.jobpositiondescription)
              AND max(jp1.jobpositiondescription) = 'Relief Teacher' THEN
           max(jp1.jobpositiondescription)
         ELSE
           stuff((SELECT ' / ' + jp2.jobpositiondescription
                         FROM dbo.vstaffjobpositions jp2
                         WHERE jp2.staffid = jp1.staffid
                               AND jp2.jobpositiondescription <> 'Relief Teacher'
                         FOR XML
                             PATH ('')),
                 1,
                 3,
                 '')
       END staffposition
       FROM dbo.vstaffjobpositions jp1
       GROUP BY jp1.staffid, 
                jp1.staffnameexternal;
```

Comment: Great! Thank you for explaining where I was making mistake and many thanks to show how to solve this with the result which I expect.